# Refusal Note for Swiss Visa applied in 2010

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-refusals, switzerland, minors

I had a visa refusal from India to Switzerland in 2010. My daughter's passport was linked with mine as she was minor then.We were not given any refusal reason by the travel agency. Now my daughter will be applying for her student visa to the UK. I would like a refusal note from the Swiss Embassy, Please advice on how to go about it.

Comment: Have you contacted them to ask for a copy of the refusal notice?

Comment: It is not the question, but it should not matter on outcome. Ev. she should tell that she was refused visa for Switzerland (if asked: do not lie or hide information). But it should not affect her possibilities: she was minor, so it was not her fault (and she was not refused the visa). I assume in 2010 neither UK nor CH would have considered your passport as her. We require separate passport since long time.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.